# Why is getcomputedstyle a method of window rather than element?

Tags: javascript, dom

Why is it necessary to write:

`window.getComputedStyle(element);`

rather than the object-oriented:

`element.getComputedStyle();`

Comment: Because someone in charge designed it this way? Also, an element doesn't have to be in the DOM, and if so, I assume the browser cannot know the computed styles, because if not in the DOM, the element will not be affected by any styles other than maybe inline styles, and even those will probably not be computed for performance reasons.

Comment: @connexo I don't see how your second point about disconnected elements suggests that this should be a global function rather than a method of the element.

Comment: In fact, it seems like it should be exactly the opposite -- if the element isn't in the DOM, why are we using a method of the DOM rather than a method of the element?

Comment: A method on the element could be misleading and suggest that you can use it even if disconnected, and find out how an element *would* render, were it connected. But that is just speculation.

Comment: Someone wrote it and made the specification say it extends the window interface. :) Make a proposal to add it to element and I am sure someone will shoot it down with some reason why it is bad. :)